# Super JUnit classes with no test cases

Tags: java, junit

I have three JUnit test classes that all had some common code, including identical setup() methods.  So, I factored this code out into its own class that extends TestCase and now have the three earlier JUnit test classes extend this new class.  The new super class contains no tests itself.

However, in our build, JUnit runs all the JUnit test classes, including the new super class with no tests.  It gives this error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.acme.ControllerTest
```

I could get rid of this error by creating some simple test that does nothing in ControllerTest.  But is there a cleaner way of fixing this?

Comment: Is ControllerTest abstract? I dont think JUnit runs tests in abstract classes from memory

Comment: No, it's not abstract.  I will try that.

Comment: Excellent - see my answer for how to do it in JUnit 4 as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me

### JUnit 3

```
public abstract class BaseTest extends TestCase {

    public void setUp(){
        System.out.println("before called");
    }
}

public class Test1 extends BaseTest {

    public void test() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
        System.out.println("Test1");
    }   
}

public class Test2 extends BaseTest {

    public void test() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
        System.out.println("Test2");
    }   
}
```

The output I get is

```
before called
Test2
before called
Test1
```

### JUnit 4

For JUnit4 you do not even need to make the base class abstract. You can just use the following

```
public class BaseTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        System.out.println("before called");
    }
}

public class Test1 extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
        System.out.println("Test1");
    }   
}

public class Test2 extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
        System.out.println("Test1");
    }   
}
```

I would strongly recommend using JUnit 4. Using annotations means that you break some of this inheritance dependency which can get confusing.

Comment: I know this question is a little old, but can you help me understand why you're even bothering to say assertTrue(true)? Why not just leave it out?

Comment: @rbwhitaker just to make it a bit more test like ;) They are not needed in this example

Comment: Fair enough. We've been having a discussion at work at whether there's a practical use for assertTrue(true). We couldn't come up with anything. Since your example code used it, I wondered if you knew something we weren't thinking about. But I can understand why you'd do it here. Kind of a way of saying, "Put in real test stuff here." Just filler code, I suppose. Thanks!